# Fazer um programa em c para calcular o valor da raiz de uma função usando método da bisseção porém, variavel esta sempre igual a zero

Tags: c

olá estou querendo fazer um programa em c que calcule a raiz de uma função usando o método da bisseção, porém, a variável que era para ter valor atribuído por quem digitasse, está tendo o valor 0 sempre que eu a chamo pelo printf tornando complicado eu descobrir em que parte do programa eu estou errando ou se estou errando desde o início, se possível dizer o que está causando isso agradeceria. Se o meu programa para calcular  a raiz de uma função usando método da bisseção estiver errado e vocês puderem informar o que eu agradeceria também.

ah e a função é x²-1.

aqui está o código:

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    float g = 0;
    int i = 0;
    float a = 0;
    float b = 0;
    float n = 0;
    float v = 0;
    float h = 0;
    float y = 0;

    printf("digite o numero do valor do erro ex: 0.001;0.1 etc.\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &g);
    printf("\ndigite o ponto A onde o mesmo seja o valor o mesmo seja o valor anterior a umas das raizes da funcao \n ");
    scanf_s("%f", &a);
    printf("\ndigite o ponto B onde o mesmo seja o valor posterior a umas das raizes da funcao\n ");
    scanf_s("%f", &b);
    printf("\n");


    do
    {
        n = (a + b) / 2;
        h = (pow(a, 2) - 1);
        y = (pow(b, 2) - 1);
        v = h * y;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            if (v == 0)
            {
                float q = ((pow(a, 2)) - 1);
                if (q == 0)
                {
                    printf("o valor da raiz e %f\n", &a);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("o valor da raiz é %f \n", &b);
                }
            }
            if (v > 0)
            {
                i = i - 1;
                printf("digite novamente os valores de a e b, voce digitou valores errados\n");
                scanf_s("%f", &a);
                scanf_s("%f\n", &b);
            }
            i++;

        }
        else
        {

            if (v == 0)
            {
                printf("o valor de uma das raizes e%f \n", &b);
            }
            if (v > 0)
            {
                a = b;
            }
            b = n;
            i++;
            if ((b - n) <= g)
            {
                printf("o valor de uma das raizes aproximadamente e%f \n", &b);
            }
        }

    } while ((b - n) <= g);



    return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: é que esta usando o `&`  quando usa o `print`  ... Quando uma o `&`  esta acessando endereço de memoria e nao o valor que precisa.

Comment: Olhe como esta no código `printf("o valor de uma das raizes e%f \n", &b);`  **mas** deveria remover o `&`  ficando dessa forma   `printf("o valor da raiz é %f \n", b);`

Comment: eu removi o & o programa compila porém agr da o erro quando eu digito o valor da 1 variavel o erro se lê da seguinte forma: expression: result_pointer != nullptr

Comment: é que o `scanf_s()` faz parte da lib C11 uma versão mais  segura do `scanf()` e não é um  padrão do `C` nem todos  compiladores implementam essa lib C11. Então tente usar o `scanf()` a não ser que realmente precise do `scanf_s()`